# Ejecutar una dll desde python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy tratando de ejecutar una dll desde python.

Me encontré este código

```
# Importamos ctypes
import ctypes as c

# acceso a la biblioteca
dll = c.CDLL("funciones.dll")

# acceso a la variable global de la biblioteca
# longitud del array
size = c.c_int.in_dll(dll, 'tam').value

# se establece el tipo de dato (en C) que retornará la función
dll.promedio.restype = c.c_float

# de esta forma se declara un array de enteros con ctypes 
vector = c.c_int * size

# se define al array
v = vector(10,20,13,14,5,16)
```

Al ejecutar el programa me indica:

```
OsError [WinError 193] %1 no es una aplicación WIN32 válida.
```

Estuve buscando en los foros e indican que el problema puede ser que este tratando de ejecutar una dll de 32 bits en python de 64.

Entonces, como estaba utilizando Python de 64, cambié a python de 32 bits y tampoco funciona.

Ahora. Lo mas extraño es que si ejecuto el interprete de python y voy ejecutando instrucción por instrucción el programa si funciona y no marca error; solo lo hace cuando el archivo .py.

Alguien sabrá algo al respecto?

Saludos !

Comment: Efectivamente la causa mas común es la que comentas, pero me parece muy extraño que funcione con el intérprete interactivo y no ejecutando el script ¿Estás seguro de estar ejecutando el script con el mismo intérprete con el que pruebas sentencia a sentencia (interprete interactivo)?

Comment: Prueba 2 cosas: usa la ruta absoluta de `funciones.dll`  y añade lo siguiente a tu script : `import sys` `print(sys.version)`, este ultimo comando imprimira la version de python que estas realmente usando.

Comment: Encontre la solucion gracias mi hermano   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-M2AmmFKX8